# How to create a reference key from given details

Tags: sql-server

```
Create table test1
(
    id bigint Not Null,
    name varchar(10) Not Null
    constraint pk_test primary key(id,name)
)
Create table test2
(
    Mid bigint Not Null references test1(id) ,
    MSalary varchar(10) Not Null
)
```

In test2 I am not able to create a reference to test1 id Please help me..
Thanks in Advance!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need a foreign key in order to reference a table. Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE test1
(
    id bigint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchat(10) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE test2
(
    Mid bigint NOT NULL,
    MSalary varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (Mid) REFERENCES test1(id)
)
```

Comment: Thanks Trickery for take a interest in my question, but actually i need a composite key in table test1. how could it possible.. It gives error....